# Random Number with a predefined width in F#

Tags: f#

How can I defined the width of a random number?

```
let randomNumber = System.Random()
let randomBarcodePart2 = randomNumber.Next(**000000, 999999**)
```

I have this now, but is it possible to generate a random number, where we only defined the width.

Like this:

```
let randomBarcodePart2 = randomNumber.Next(6)
```

Comment: `String.PadLeft`  IDK how do it in F# but its probably something similar to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple example with printf:

```
let t = randomNumber.Next(0,999999)
printfn "%07i" t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a type extension:

```
type System.Random with
    member x.Width w =
        x.Next(0, pown 10 w - 1)
        |> sprintf "%0*d" w
```

Here's a few outputs

```
Random().Width 6;;
val it : string = "985326"

Random().Width 9;;
val it : string = "803426947"

Random().Width 1;;
val it : string = "6"
```